# How can I specify HTML5 output from RMarkdown to get semantic elements like <section>?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I noticed that in HTML produced by `knitr` from my RMarkdown document, sections are marked up thus:

```
<div id="chunk_id" class="section level2">
<h2>...</h2>
<p>...</p>
</div>
```

and so on. I think it's best practice to use a `<section>` element rather than a `<div>` here ([reference 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines), [reference 2](https://bitsofco.de/sectioning-content-in-html5/)), so I forked the RMarkdown code to see if I could make a change and a PR. [In the code](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/html_document.R) I found the following:

> ````
> #'@param section_divs Wrap sections in <div> tags (or <section> tags in HTML5),
> #'  and attach identifiers to the enclosing <div> (or <section>) rather than the
> #'  header itself. ```
> ````

so it seems like there is no need for a change to RMarkdown - it will already use `<section>` in the way I want, *if* it is told to output HTML5.

My question is: how do you tell `knitr` to output HTML5? I have

```
output:
    html_document:
        section_divs = TRUE
```

but no idea how to "switch on" HTML5.

Comment: Short answer: sorry, but you can't. A lot of things in the R Markdown ecosystem depend on the `div` tag. We can't easily switch to `section`. In the foreseeable future, we will continue using `div`. I'll revise the documentation. Thanks!